# core.exception.OutOfMemoryError@(0) using a large dynamic array

Tags: arrays, d, biginteger, dynamic-arrays

```
import std.math;
import std.bigint;
import std.stdio;

BigInt sum_min_pfactor(long N){
    BigInt f(int n) {
        return BigInt(n)*(BigInt(n)+1) / 2 - 1;
    }

    int v = cast(int)(sqrt(float(N)));

    bool[] used;
    used.length = v+1;

    BigInt ret;
    BigInt finish;

    BigInt[] s_sum,s_cnt,l_cnt,l_sum;
    s_sum.length = v+1;
    l_sum.length = v+1;
    s_cnt.length = v+1;
    l_cnt.length = v+1;

    for (long i = 0; i <= v; i++) {
        s_cnt[i] = i - 1;
        s_sum[i] = f(cast(int)i);
    }

    for (long i = 1; i <= v; i++) {
        l_cnt[i] = N / cast(int)i - 1;
        l_sum[i] = f(cast(int)(N) / cast(int)i);
    }

    for (long p = 2; p <= v; p++) {
        if (s_cnt[p] == s_cnt[p-1]) {
            continue;
        }

        BigInt p_cnt = s_cnt[p-1];
        BigInt p_sum = s_sum[p - 1];
        long q = p * p;

        ret = ret + p * (l_cnt[p] - p_cnt);
        l_cnt[1] = l_cnt[1] - l_cnt[p] + p_cnt;
        l_sum[1] = l_sum[1] - (l_sum[p] - p_sum) * p;

        long interval = (p & 1) + 1;

        if (v > N / q) {
            finish = N / q;
        }
        else {
            finish = v; 
        }

        for (long i = p+interval; i <= finish; i += interval){
            if (used[i]) {
                continue;
            }

            long d = i * p;

            if (d <= v) {
                l_cnt[i] = l_cnt[i] - l_cnt[d] + p_cnt;
                l_sum[i] = l_sum[i] - (l_sum[d] - p_sum) * p;
            }
            else {
                long t = N / d;   
                l_cnt[i] = l_cnt[i] - s_cnt[t] + p_cnt;
                l_sum[i] = l_sum[i] - (s_sum[t] - p_sum) * p;
            }
        }

        if (q <= v) {
            for (long i = q; i < finish; i += p*interval){
                used[i] = true;
            }
        }

        for (long i = v; i >= q - 1; i--) {
            long t = i / p;
            s_cnt[i] = s_cnt[i] - s_cnt[t] + p_cnt;
            s_sum[i] = s_sum[i] - (s_sum[t] - p_sum) * p;
        }
    }
    return l_sum[1] + ret;
}

void main () {
    writeln(sum_min_pfactor(pow(10,12)));
}
```

The code above works perfectly when dealing with numbers below 10^9. However, after that it starts giving incorrect values and crashes with a memory error when trying to compute an answer for 10^9. I'm using the BigInt library but my guess is one of the variables that is not declared as BigInts is messing up my results. I'm also assuming the memory error is caused by the size of the dynamic arrays, but I can't figure out how to solve that particular problem.

Comment: Compile with -g and it should tell you exactly where the exception is thrown, unless you already know.

Comment: Are you compiling as 32 bit or 64 bit? If it is 32 bit, you have less memory available, and the garbage collector is more likely to accidentally pin large arrays and not free them (with a large array on 32 bit, the odds that a false pointer will point to it is somewhat high, and then the GC will think it might still be in use and thus not free it)

Comment: Tried compiling with both the -g and -m64 flag, but nothing changed. Output did not tell me where the exception happens, but I know it occurs when declaring the BigInt vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a silent integer overflow in the `std.math.pow()` function.

The output of

```
writefln("%d", pow(10, 12));
writefln("%d", pow(10, 12L));
```

is

```
-727379968
1000000000000
```

Now `sqrt(-727379968)` is `-nan`. Cast to integer gives `int.min`, which is about -2 GiB. The `length` property of the arrays is unsigned. Therefore each array is `type.sizeof` * 2 GiB in size which explains the out-of-memory error.

Solution: add suffix L to one or both numbers, e.g.

```
writeln(sum_min_pfactor(pow(10L,9L)));
```

Comment: While that does work for 10^9, it gives incorrect values for 10^10 and higher. 10^10 should be 2220827932427240957, while D returns 2244705520836203068 (strange since it's actually a higher value than the correct answer, so I'm not sure if it's an overflow issue this time).

Comment: I did not look at your calculation. My point is that `pow(int,int)` returns wrong values starting with 10^10. With the use of `pow(long,long)` the OutOfMemoryError should be gone.

Comment: At least starting with 10^14 your calculation also suffers from integer overflow: cast(int)(N) truncates some bits from N.

Comment: But the error in values happen even earlier. I've already set pow to use longs, but I don't know what else could be causing them.

Comment: Change the parameter type from f(int) to f(long) and remove all cast(int). Then you get the right answer for 10^10 if you start with pow(10,10L).

Comment: Great, works now! It's seriously slower than I thought, more so considering the Nim version (which uses an unoptimized 128 bit library) computes 10^12 in 6 seconds. It will have to do I guess.